# Magical function in SpriteBuilder projects

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

In cocos2d tutorials people initialize sprites/physical nodes in the init method, but in the cocos2d + SpriteBuilder tutorials it's written in this method:

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {}
```

In cocos2d only tutorials there is a method like that,but there is a line of code, that says what a kind of method it is,right? :

```
- (void)onEnter{ 
[super onEnter];
}
```

So, 'didLoadFromCCB' is a magical method for SpriteBuilder projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The didLoadFromCCB method is sent to each node after the node has been loaded by CCBReader. It runs that method when it is implemented by that node's class. It behaves like a protocol method without having to implement a protocol (nor is there a protocol). See also [this github issue](https://github.com/spritebuilder/SpriteBuilder/issues/613).

The CCBReader method that runs didLoadFromCCB does so like this after loading is complete:

```
+ (void) callDidLoadFromCCBForNodeGraph:(CCNode*)nodeGraph
{
    for (CCNode* child in nodeGraph.children)
    {
        [CCBReader callDidLoadFromCCBForNodeGraph:child];
    }

    if ([nodeGraph respondsToSelector:@selector(didLoadFromCCB)])
    {
        [nodeGraph performSelector:@selector(didLoadFromCCB)];
    }
}
```

The onEnter method is defined by the CCNode class, so it is documented in the CCNode class reference and Xcode is able to suggest the method when starting to type it.